# Update siblings and parent record in the same after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map, master-detail

I have written a code to update all the sibling's and parent contact's field when one of the child records have been updated. The logic here is to make checkbox false on all the siblings and parent record if the checkbox has been checked on one of the child record. Below is the code, I am achieving the functionality but the code is not optimized and I want to achieve it through Maps if it is possible. Still trying to learn maps efficiently. Please help me optimizing the code.

```
    trigger Addressflag on Address__c (After update, After Insert) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert){
    List<ID> ConIds = new List<ID>();
    Boolean needsUpdate = FALSE; 
    for (Address__c Adds: trigger.new)
    {
    ConIds.add(Adds.contact__c);
    }
    system.debug('parent con ids'+ConIds);
    contact con = [select id, checkbox__c, recordTypeId from contact where Id IN :conIds];
    List<Address__c> otherAlt = new List<Address__c>([select id, contact__c, checkbox__c, contact__r.recordTypeId from Address__c where contact__c in: conIDs]);
        for (Address__c adds: trigger.new)
        {
            for (integer i=0; i < otherAlt.size(); i++)
            {
                if ((otherAlt[i].contact__c==adds.contact__c) && (otherAlt[i].id != adds.id))
                {
                     otherAlt[i].checkbox__c = FALSE;
                     con.checkbox__c=FALSE;
                     needsUpdate = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }

        if(checkrecursive.runOnce())
        {
              if (needsUpdate)
              {
                  update otherAlt;
                  update con;
              }
        }
    }
 }
```

Please tell me how can I use a **Map** if it is applicable. Here contact is the parent and address is the child having master detail.

Comment: apple123 -- I heartily recommend you study the Apex Developer docs and look at the example apps that illustrate maps (for example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the advice I am doing that, but is there anyway you can help me optimizing it? That was my question initially.

Comment: @cropredy Can you help with MAP in above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've asked me to look at this, I've modified the first part of your solution to use maps (your query of `List<Address__c> otherAlt` was written to return a map) and completed your code to create a map of results for update.

I'm not certain that the map revisions to your existing code will be all that more efficient than what you'd already written, but it's at least easier to read. With that having been said, here's what you've asked for. The other mapping will clearly help you with what you were trying to do.

```
trigger Addressflag on Address__c (After update, After Insert) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert){
        List<ID> ConIds = new List<ID>();
        for (Address__c Adds: trigger.new)
        {
            ConIds.add(Adds.contact__c);
        }
        system.debug('parent con ids'+ConIds);
        map<Id,contact>conMap = new map([select id, checkbox__c, recordTypeId from  contact where Id IN :conIds]);
        map<Id,Address__c>AddrssMap = new map<Id,Address__c>([select id, contact__c, checkbox__c, contact__r.recordTypeId from Address__c where contact__c in: conIDs]);


        Map<Id,map<Id,Contact>>ConsForUp = new map<Id,map<Id,Contact>>();    
        for (Address__c adds: trigger.new)
        {
            for(Id aId2: AddrssMap.keyset())
            {
                if ((AddrssMap.get(aId2).contact__c==adds.contact__c) && (aId2 != adds.Id))
                {
                    AddrssMap.get(aId2).checkbox__c = FALSE;
                    conMap.get(adds.contact__c).checkbox__c = FALSE
                    if(conMap.get(adds.contact__c).checkbox__c = FALSE){
                         ConsForUp.put(adds.contact__c,conMap);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        //*** Revised update method below *** 
        if(checkrecursive.runOnce())
        {
            list<Contact>toUpdate = new list<Contact>();

            for(Id cId : ConsForUp.keyset())
            {
                 toUpdate.addAll(ConsForUp.get(cId).values());
                 // above is a map of id to map, so first we extract the map, then the map's values()
                 // which results in a list of contacts for each map that we add together              
            }
            update toUpdate; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The above code has not been tested or debugged. Use at your own risk. ;)

**Edit in resp to comments**

The above trigger queries `contacts` then puts the results into a map. After you apply the results of your manipulations and perform the update on the results, any `BeforeUpdate` triggers you have on the `Contact` object would be expected to execute. They shouldn't execute until after your code in *the above* trigger has initiated the update (regardless of whether `afterInsert` or `afterUpdate` on `Address__c`).

Once that occurs, any `BeforeUpdate` triggers on `Contact` would indeed be expected to execute. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) in the Apex Developer Guide. Any updates caused by *the above* trigger must satisfy the requirements of your validation trigger on `Contacts`. If not, the entire transaction will be rolled back.

If you have multiple triggers on `Contact`, I recommend you combine them into a single trigger. Until you do, you won't be able to control the order of execution of those triggers. They will execute in a random order each time they're called. If there's any workflow on `Contact`, your `Contact AfterUpdate` triggers will be called one additional time.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. I have one question here, I do see that we are updating parent contacts, but will it also update the sibling addresses? For example if I have 4 addresses related to a contact, If I update checkbox on one of the addresses trigger should update contact and other 3 addresses as well.

Comment: I simply followed your logic. If you want all of them to update if one matches, you'll need to change the logic. Add a nested NeedsUpdate into the if statement or something along those lines. or create a list until you've checked all of the related children to see if one needs an update before doing the put to the map.

Comment: I am getting error in this line " conMap.get(adds.contact__c).checkbox__c = FALSE" as **Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Id**

Comment: I revised the code. The beginning of that for loop was declared as an Id not as `for (Address__c adds: trigger.new)`. That should take care of the issue. Am surprised it even compiled.

Comment: sir, thank you so much for your help. I am facing an issue, I have an apex before update trigger and several other triggers on contacts. While I am creating new contact it is triggering the before update trigger somehow. It is strange as the record still has not been inserted to the database. I have developed it to give a validation in before insert trigger and before update as well. But while creating record before update trigger is getting called and it gives error. What can I do?

Comment: See my edited response. Without seeing details of your revised trigger, I suggest you focus on order of execution. That would explain behavior you're asking about.

Comment: yes, I did see the flow of execution as a first step. What is happening is when I try to put trigger.old value on an insert in before update trigger, it is printing trigger.old somehow and then trigger.new same value.  I will still work around it. Sir I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You may need to add a checkbox that tells you it's being updated by this trigger and to not run all the logic of the `beforeUpdate` trigger on Contact if true, but instead, only to change the value of the checkbox to false so it clears it for you. Have this trigger set that checkbox to true before updating contact.

Comment: I ll try this, but what is happening is even If I try to make it run for before update due to some conditions before update is getting triggered. I will definitely try this.
in above code I am getting erorr [List<Map<Id,Contact>>].values() on DML statement.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Create a for loop to pull out the maps first, then get the values from each map which will be lists of contacts. You can then add the lists of contacts together. Apologies, I didn't think that last part through.